# List created for delivery number, totalpages,page number need to find the missing page number if any using c#

Tags: c#, list

Three lists created for one document data which has delivery number , total pages, page number for every document .
Now i need to get missing page number for the delivery number as

For every delivery number (8181828384) i will have totalpages like (05) and page numbers (01,02,03,04,05)
for the delivery number i need to get the missing page if any .
please suggest.

```
 class Student
    {
        public string DeliveryNo { get; set; }
        public string TotalPgs { get; set; }
        public string  Page { get; set; }
    }
        public static void IAReport_Prepare (IBatchNodeData node)
        {

        }

        public static void IAReport_Finish (IBatchNodeData node)
        {
             IBatchNodeData[] customevalues = node.GetStepNode ("CustomValues").GetDescendantNodes(1);
             IBatchNodeData[] Docs = node.GetStepNode ("IAReport").GetDescendantNodes(1);
            // List<string> data = new List<string>();

            //  List<string[]> EmpDtls = new List<string[]>(); 

           IList<Student> studentList = new List<Student>();

              foreach (IBatchNodeData doc in customevalues)
             {
                string  Deliveryno  =  doc.ReadString("SapDeliveryNo");
                string totpages  =  doc.ReadString("TotalPages");
                string pageno  =  doc.ReadString("PageNumber");                 



        new Student() { DeliveryNo = Deliveryno, TotalPgs = totpages , Page = pageno } ;

           }
var groupedResult = from s in studentList group s by s.DeliveryNo;


foreach (var ageGroup in groupedResult) // getting error here please suggest.
{
    Console.WriteLine("Age Group: {0}", ageGroup .Key); //Each group has a key 

     foreach(Student s in ageGroup)` // Each group has inner collection
        Console.WriteLine("Student Name: {0}", s.Page);
}
```

Comment: please add some code and specify your question

Comment: if you just want to test if a page number field is NULL, you can write a query and find missing page numbers in your records. But.. fubo is right !! without more information and context, it will be difficult to answer.. Tag your database platform and add the code you use. Also, you will have to state  your user requirement more accurately. Currently, it is not clear what you try to do !

Comment: List<string[]> EmpDtls = new List<string[]>();    
             foreach (IBatchNodeData doc in customevalues)
          {
                string  Deliveryno  =  doc.ReadString("SapDeliveryNo");
              string totpages  =  doc.ReadString("TotalPages");
              string pageno  =  doc.ReadString("PageNumber");               
                
            string[] empDtl1 = new string[] { Deliveryno, totpages, pageno };           
             EmpDtls.Add(empDtl1);  
          }

Comment: will get the data as given below now i need to find out 
            MissingFieldException page number if any . please suggest
              
            {8528523698,02,01}
            {8528523698,02,02}
            {8635563697,03,01}
            {8635563697,03,02}
            {8635563697,03,03}

Comment: @surya please click "edit" to update the question istead of using comments

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can sort data by delivery number and page number and filter by last page and new page number

```
foreach (var doc in customevalues.OrderBy(p => p.DeliveryNumber).ThenBy(p => p.PageNumber))
{
    if (currentDeliveryNumber != page.DeliveryNumber)
    {
        currentDeliveryNumber = page.DeliveryNumber;
        lastPage = 0;
    }

    var pageDiff = page.PageNumber - (lastPage + 1);

    if (pageDiff > 0)
    {
        do
        {
            var numberPage = lastPage + pageDiff;
        }
        while (--pageDiff > 0);
    }
    lastPage = page.PageNumber;
}
```